# Javascript Isn't Getting User's Profile Name And ID

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, database, comments

I'm making an AJAX/JavaScript comment function on each user's wall. 
The PHP I'm using to get the user's info from the database is this:

```
$fetchstats = (int)strip_tags(rawurldecode($_GET['id']));

if (isset($fetchstats)) {
    $fetchstats = mysql_real_escape_string($fetchstats);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$fetchstats."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {    
        $userp = mysql_fetch_array ( $res, MYSQLI_ASSOC ); 
    } else { 
        exit;
    }
} else {
    exit;
}
```

So Each variable for the user's info is like this: `$userp['username']`, and that will display that user's username.

The problem I'm having is when I submit a comment on their page, it gets my name, ID and the comment to insert into the database, but not their name and ID. Here's the insert PHP function which is in `comment_insert.php`:

```
$username = $username;
$user_id = $id;
$wall_user = $userp['username'];
$wall_id = $userp['id'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$timestamp = time();

if ($_POST) {
    $insert = ("INSERT INTO comments (username, user_id, wall_user, wall_id, comment, timestamp) VALUES ('$username', '$user_id', '$wall_user', '$wall_id', '$comment', '$timestamp')");
}
```

The JavaScript function then calls the file and gets the comment to insert. Here it is:

```
function Comment(Name,ID) {
    var comment = $('#comment').val();
    var dataString = 'comment=' + comment;

    if (comment.length < 1) {
        alert('You Must Enter A Comment!');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_insert.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (Message) {
            $('#Comments').html(Message);
            $('#Comments').fadeIn('slow').html(comment);        
            alert(Message);     
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is there any reason why it wouldn't get the user's name and ID from their profile?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to clarify your problem...

Comment: The comment_insert.php Isn't Getting The User's Name And ID.

Answer (score 1):

If I guess it right, you didn't pass the User's Name and ID to the PHP script

```
function Comment(_Name,_ID) {
    var comment = $('#comment').val();

    // compose your post data like this instead of a string
    var data = {
        'comment': comment,
        'username': _Name,
        'id' : _ID 
    }

    if (comment.length < 1) {
        alert('You Must Enter A Comment!');
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comment_insert.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (Message) {
                $('#Comments').html(Message);
                $('#Comments').fadeIn('slow').html(comment);        
                alert(Message);     
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: So Would I use PHP for the _Name and _ID?

Comment: No. You want to pass the _Name and _ID to the PHP script, correct? In the data object, there are 'username' and 'id' elements. You can access them with $_POST['username'] and $_POST['id']

Comment: So make a hidden field In the form such as:
<input type="hidden" id="wall_id" value="<?php echo $userp['id']" />  
<input type="hidden" id="wall_user" value="<?php echo $userp['username']" />

Comment: For what? BTW, switch to PDO because mysql_* functions are being deprecated.

Comment: You said to do $_POST['username'] .. The PHP is getting my username and my ID, Not theres. I changed the coding to what you posted and made 2 hidden inputs, but not working.

Comment: `var data = {
        'comment': comment,
        'wall_user': wall_user,
        'wall_id' : wall_id
    }`
I have that in the javascript now and this in the user.php HTML..
    `<input type="hidden" id="wall_id" value="<?php echo $userp['wall_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="wall_user" value="<?php echo $userp['wall_user'] ?>" />`

Comment: Sorry I'm at a lost then. It appears I misunderstood your question and I'm not able to keep up with your problem anymore.

Comment: The problem is The PHP's not getting the User's Id and name to insert into the database.